# Quick and easy application/UI for Python forecasting script

Tags: python, user-interface

I've made a script for forecasting time series data in Python 3. I've made this for a colleague of mine, however he has no knowledge of Python or coding in general. So  I was thinking about making some sort of app with an GUI for him, so he can run the program locally on his computer, and pass maybe 2-3 arguments to the underlying script.

Can this be achieved in pure Python, and if yes, in what libraries? If not, what are the alternatives? What considerations should I make?

I've never done this before, so I'm looking for something beginner friendly.

**EDIT:**

So, in my script I query some time series from an SQL server, and then process it. In my GUI/dashboard I need to be able to pass the time interval and a string parameter for selecting multiple time series (some id that selects the wanted time series).

Comment: GUI modules: tkinter (preinstalled), PyQt, PySide, wxPython, PyGTK (Linux), etc. Web frameworks: Django, Flask, Bottle, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dash](https://plot.ly/dash/) is an open source framework from plotly that is made for exactly this. Lots of out of the box components for visualizing your model and can be written in pure Python.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using python and QtPy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Streamlit or Plotly Dash. Both are Python packages that can build a frond-end interface and interactions. However, it's pretty time-consuming if you want to build a user-friendly interface.

Another solution is to use low-code app development tools, such as [Acho](https://acho.io/). It can integrate Python models and build a user-friendly interface on top of it.